# How to read an SQL database, then select first hit and save it?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x

I'm wondering how can I read a database, with lots of entries per client, and select only the last interaction of each one in the last 3 months? If no interaction is found I should be able to see it as well.

The table is similar to this:

Client name | Operation performed | DateTime

How can I do this efficiently? It is a very large table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your query pull in all of your **Clients** and then left join to what I am calling your **ClientOperations** table getting your most recent record in the last 3 months. I am doing that with the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) window function.

Your query should look something like this...

```
SELECT
          c.ClientID
        , c.ClientName
        , co.OperationPerformed
        , co.OperationDateTime
FROM      Clients c
LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT
                    *
                  , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY OperationDateTime DESC) AS rn
              FROM  ClientOperations
              WHERE CONVERT (DATE, OperationDateTime) >= CONVERT (DATE, DATEADD (MONTH, -3, GETDATE ()))
          )        co ON c.ClientID = co.ClientID
                     AND co.rn      = 1;
```

Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=15f059bead43efd0fdd916c490014ab3) with sample data.